# Android - Lock orientation to two directions only

Tags: android, screen-orientation

How can make my android application to be Landscape or portrait but without the reverse directions?

Meaning that I want to enable `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` and `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` but to disable `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE` and `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem/feature request in my camera app, and found this post:

[android camera surfaceview orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157984/android-camera-surfaceview-orientation/5183690#5183690)

In changeRotation just comment `ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED` and `ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED`, and create a method `rotateViews(int degrees)` to rotate all of the images(buttons) of your layout when switching between regular landscape/portrait.

Also,

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

worked better for me than

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR | ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: You can't combine ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_* values together (as flags), because they represent simple numbers from 0 to 14 (simply they are not flags).

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you notify the system that you want to handle orientation changes by adding "orientation" to the [`android:configChanges`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) flag attribute in the activity tag in your manifest file.
- Override [`Activity.onConfigurationChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) and inspect the [`Configuration.orientation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation) field in the passed `Configuration` parameter and set the orientation of the activity to either [`ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) or [`ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) using [`Activity.setRequestedOrientation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29) appropriately.

Comment: When the method Activity.onConfigurationChanged is called I get only '1' or '2', same value for portrait or for portrait reverse.
I tried to use Activity.setRequestedOrientation to change the orientation to portrait or lanscape not reverse and it worked. The problem is that Activity.onConfigurationChanged is never called again.

Comment: What do you mean by onConfigurationChanged is never called again?  You mean until the program is done executing?

Comment: It was called when I first caused orientation to happen, and then as many times I tried, it was never called again. I think this is because the method setRequestedOrientation().