# Setting Multi Orientation - Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-orientation

I'm new at android programming and I've got a problem with orientation.

I want my activities only to be viewable in the portrait and reverse-portrait and orientations.

I thought `android:screenOrientation="portrait|reversePortrait"`  would work but it is not working. Is there have any way to do this in the manifest file?

Comment: check this


  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7686539/849939

Comment: for anyone who lives the same situation in API15, you should write android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" not sensorPortrait

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please check the documentation:
 http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

In API 9+ added that portrait orientation, but can be either normal or reverse portrait based on the device sensor. So you can use `android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"` for both.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i checked the documentation before but i missed it. Sorry for this spammy question.

Comment: Any way or restricting to only portrait and landscape? (non-reverse)

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927486/android-lock-orientation-to-two-directions-only