# I want my android application in landscape and portrait mode only?

Tags: android

I am developing one camera application.I want my application should be in landscape and portrait only.If mobile changes to reverse landscape, application should remain in portrait or landscape mode.And one thing is if device rotated to landscape application should change to landscape, and device changes to portrait, application changes to portrait.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/19364640/3419997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Potrait Mode then:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

If you want Landscape Mode then:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Comment: if i specify this in manifest file how can i change to landscape and portrait mode without reverse portrait

Comment: @SujithKs By default your app will only move in portrait and landscape mode. If you don't want your app to support reverse potrait then don't do anything.

Comment: i want to lock reverse landscape also.when my device changes to reverse landscape whole application screen is rotating to reverse landscape.

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:screenOrientation= locked on android manifest.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html for more info

Comment: if i want only landscape and portrait in my application how can i specify it in manifest file