# Image saved with wrong orientation

Tags: android, camera, commonsware

I am using this code:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Camera/Picture/src/com/commonsware/android/picture/PictureDemo.java

where in `Manifest`, `Activity Orientation` is set to **Landscape**.

So, its like allowing user to take picture only in Landscape mode, and if the picture is taking by holding the device in portrait mode, the image saved is like this:

[image]

**a 90 degree rotated image.**

After searching for a solution, I found this:

[Android - Camera preview is sideways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841122/android-camera-preview-is-sideways)

**where the solution is:**

in `surfaceChanged()` check for

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
display.getRotation();
```

and change the **Camera's displayOrientation** accordingly.

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

But no matter how many times I rotate the device, `surfaceChanged()` never gets called.

I even tried removing `orientation="Landscape"` in the **Manifest.xml**, but then the preview itself is shown sideways(may be because default `android.view.SurfaceView` is supposed to be in **Landscape mode**?).

Comment: check this link, it may be useful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157984/android-camera-surfaceview-orientation

Comment: Well, there *are* reasons why I'm no longer covering this code in the book... :-) I left it in the repo for historical reasons, but there are certainly issues with it. FWIW, I do plan on revisiting this topic in the coming months, with an eye towards ironing out this sort of problem, and I have made a note to investigate this then. However, right now, I have no particular advice for you -- my apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
        camParam = camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        String currentversion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK;
        Log.d("System out", "currentVersion " + currentversion);
        int currentInt = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        Log.d("System out", "currentVersion " + currentInt);

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            if (currentInt != 7) {
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            } else {
                Log.d("System out", "Portrait " + currentInt);

                params.setRotation(90);

                /*
                 * params.set("orientation", "portrait");
                 * params.set("rotation",90);
                 */
                camera.setParameters(params);
            }
        }
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            // camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
            if (currentInt != 7) {
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
            } else {
                Log.d("System out", "Landscape " + currentInt);
                params.set("orientation", "landscape");
                params.set("rotation", 90);
                camera.setParameters(params);
            }
        }
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will work only for the first time because its written in `surfaceCreated()`. Later(once the preview is on) if user changes the device orientation, nothing happens and the picture taken will be sideways again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've forced your application to be landscape, your application's configuration won't change when you rotate the device, and as a result, your UI won't get redrawn. So you'll never see a surfaceCreated/Changed callback because of it.

In any case, your issue isn't with preview, it's with the captured pictures.

The camera API doesn't automatically know which way is down; it needs you to tell it how you want your images rotated by using the Camera.Parameters [setRotation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29) method. There are several coordinate systems in play here (the orientation of the camera sensor relative to your device; the orientation of your UI relative to the device; and the orientation of the device relative to the world) which have to be done correctly.

So I highly recommend you use the code provided in the setRotation documentation, and inherit from the [OrientationEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html), implementing the listener as follows:

```
 public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
   if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;
   android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
        new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
   android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
   orientation = (orientation + 45) / 90 * 90;
   int rotation = 0;
   if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
       rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;
   } else {  // back-facing camera
     rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;
   }
   mParameters.setRotation(rotation);
 }
```

This will update your camera's still picture orientation correctly so that 'up' is always up, whether your app is landscape or portrait, or your device is a tablet or a phone.