# Best way to deal with image orientation from camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I hope this question isn't marked as duplicate, but I can't find the right answer base on other questions.
I am looking for the best way to solve the orientation of camera image that can work for all devices. I tried many ways, but all of them don't work as aspect for all devices (I tested on HTC M7, Sony Experia, Samsung Galaxy and Nexus series ...). 
Here are some approaches that I tried:
[Camera orientation issue in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069122/camera-orientation-issue-in-android) 
[Android camera , onPictureTaken(byte[] imgData, Camera camera) method & PictureCallback never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504893/android-camera-onpicturetakenbyte-imgdata-camera-camera-method-picturec) 
[Android image orientation issue with custom camera activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674816/android-image-orientation-issue-with-custom-camera-activity) 
[Image saved with wrong orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098281/image-saved-with-wrong-orientation)

I even tried [this library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) but seems it can't work for all cases. And all approaches above can work for many devices, but not all (sometimes I getting failed cases (**not always**) on Nexus 4, Nexus 5 and Samsung Galaxy S4)
Is there a all-in-one solution to solve this problem? I can see some camera apps like Camera360, A better camera... that work very well. How can they do this?

Comment: "seems it can't work for all cases" -- such as? I just want to make sure that your problem areas are reflected in the outstanding issues, or are explicitly deemed out of scope.

Comment: @CommonsWare I used your library and got a problem on Galaxy S4, sometime the orientation is incorrect. As my app need to call focus camera while moving camera to make the text on document always clear. I'm not sure it is my problem. For other approaches, I often getting issues on Nexus 4 and 5.

Comment: "got a problem on Galaxy S4, sometime the orientation is incorrect" -- feel free to file an issue, with the `Build.PRODUCT` value of your specific S4 and steps to reproduce the problem with the demo app (or your own sample code to reproduce the problem, if you cannot reproduce it with the demo app).

Comment: as this is my company project and I don't have this device now, so I will do it on next week. But I want to know how can other camera apps on google play can do it without problem, can your library do the same?