# Android: Camera view fixed in Landscape and overlay view change as per orientation

Tags: android, camera, rotation

Friends,

I am stuck for days on an issue. I have a camera view fixed in Landscape mode and I would like an overlay view on top of it to change in Landscape LEFT or RIGHT directions based on the device orientation.

I have researched a lot on StackOverlay and thread below is very close to what I am looking for, but there is no solution posted here too.

[Android: Rotate only overlay Buttons on camera preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733307/android-rotate-only-overlay-buttons-on-camera-preview)

Can someone please help me to fix this obvious use case?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards,
Ashok