# TAG_ORIENTATION always 0 when capturing image - Android Surfaceholder

Tags: java, android, camera, surfaceholder

I'm trying to capture an image with `Surfaceholder` in Android and want to support both landscape and portrait photos. Have tried countless solutions now some of which worked on HTC devices but not on Samsung devices. So now I'm going for the `ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION` approach since I've read that it should work on Samsung devices as well.

```
PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){

                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] byteArray, Camera arg1) {

                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
                    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());

                    String _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "xxx" + File.separator + "xxx" + date + ".jpeg";
                    File file = new File( _path );
                    Uri uriTarget = Uri.fromFile( file );               

                    try {
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                        Bitmap realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

                        ExifInterface exif=new ExifInterface(file.getAbsolutePath());

                        Log.d("EXIF value", exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION));
                        if(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("6")){
                            realImage= rotate(realImage, 90);
                        } else if(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("8")){
                            realImage= rotate(realImage, 270);
                        } else if(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
                            realImage= rotate(realImage, 180);
                        } else if(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                            realImage= rotate(realImage, 90); //Always gets in here
                        }

                        boolean bo = realImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                        fos.close();


                        Log.d("Info", bo + "");

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.d("Info", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
                    } 
...
```

The issue I'm having is that the `TAG_ORIENTATION` always seems to be 0 no matter how I hold my device. I use an HTC for testing at the moment. Am i supposed to set the `TAG_ORIENTATION` manually or something?

And feedback appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Use this link below, very good answer to fix your issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157984/android-camera-surfaceview-orientation