# Detecting orientation like in camera app

Tags: android, android-orientation

I am developing application that is somehow similar to camera, I wish that the app will always be in landscape mode witch I achieve with:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

But I need to know when user rotates the phone to landscape mode so I can rotate the icons 90 degrees.

I have tried:

```
   if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

But it only works when I add:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

And its also change my orientation automatically.

So how can I keep my app always in Landscape mode and only detect when the phone is in Portrait without that phone automatically change anything? Just like in camera app

Comment: You can try this by comparing Device width and height, If there is a change you can rotate icons..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` is a good idea.

Now try setting your orientation manually:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you but I do not wish to change the orientation, just to know it.

Comment: @DanM This is what it does. You will get notification change event, while your orientation will not be changed.

Comment: Can you give me an example, how to use it in code and how to add listener?

Answer (score 0):

This will help. It did for me and I needed to do exactly what you needed to do.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183690/687245