# orientation changes detection with respect to time

Tags: android, handler, screen-orientation, android-orientation, thread-sleep

```
try{
            screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
            rotation = intent.getStringExtra("rotation");
            orientation = intent.getStringExtra("orientation");

        }catch(Exception e){}


        if (!screenOn) {



        } else {


            if(rotationChecker){
                Log.e("TAG","String orientationRotation above unlock");
                UnLocker();
            }
            rotationChecker=true;
            //
            //
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.e("TAG","String orientationRotation in run");
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    rotationChecker=false;
                }
            }, TIME_DELAYED);
```

i want to call unlock function when time_delayed and `rotationchecker` is true but my code not working.I need code which can keep track of last orientation and last rotation and compare with new rotation and orientation values within TIME_DELAYED value then it should call unlock function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226249/how-can-i-detect-orientation-changes-in-portrait-mode-in-android